# AND a mask to address (lower bits needed) C#

Tags: c#

So I know I can bit shift a mask of 0xFFFFFFFF by say 8 for example to get 0xFFFFFF00 & it with an address and get everything but the last 8 bits, but I would like to go the other way so I can grab the bottom end of an address with a mask like 0x000000FF, however bit shifting right wont work obviously. Any ideas?

Here is the code for the first type bit shift I mentioned.

```
public int Block_tag(int address, int block_size, int max_address)
    {
        int bit_shift = (int)Math.Log(block_size, 2);
        int bit_mask = max_address << bit_shift;
        return (address & bit_mask);
    }
```

I could do it by hand with about 12 "If" statements but that isn't very clean.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to shift? Just use the literal mask: `address & 0x000000FF`

Comment: Well I would like to shift the address of all F's so I can use the method modularly without having to hard code every shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply invert the mask use the [`~`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66.aspx) operator

```
int not_mask = ~bit_mask;
```

For example, `~0xFFFFFF00 == 0x000000FF`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that's how that operator was used. Works like a charm thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can right shift it by `(32 - number of mask bits you need)`. So if you need lower 8 bits, you can right shift by `(32-8 = 24)` bits.

Comment: I thought that too, but since I convert my strings of hex to integers for other reasons they are negative, and it causes problems. Thanks though!